# how to create RGB image from three matrices in R?

Tags: image, r, graphics, rgb

I want to create an RGB image from three 2D matrices in R. I know that there was a similar post for [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341304/how-to-display-an-image-represented-by-three-matrices-in-matlab), however I could not translate that problem to the R world.

I tried already different packages such as abind for creating a 3D array, tried to turn it into a JPEG with writeJPEG. but that did not work-

any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try with `?rgb`,

```
r <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)
g <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)
b <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)

col <- rgb(r, g, b)
dim(col) <- dim(r)

library(grid)
grid.raster(col, interpolate=FALSE)
```

Comment: perfect! that´s what I was looking for. many thanks! for all readers: the part   "dim(col) <- dim(r)" is very important :)

Comment: What is the best way to write out the rgb to a file?

Comment: anything listed in `?Devices`